# What are the different parts of a toilet seat called?

Tags: toilet

I know a toilet seat has two parts but what are they called?

Can someone find me a diagram, or just tell me what the two parts are called?  I think the top part is the lid...and the bottom part with the hole in it is the seat..am I right about this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toilet_seat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lid/cover,seat, hinge,mounting stud or bolt, retaining nuts, you could also include the bumpers if they aren't molded into the seat and lid.